# How to run a PHP script on docker?

Tags: php, docker

I have index.php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Dockerfile from the website: https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./index.php" ]
```

I build image and run container:

```
docker build -t my-php-app .
docker run -p 7000:80 --rm --name hello-world-test my-php-app
```

I see only text "Hello World" but my application doesn't work in http://localhost:7000/ why?

Comment: The container doesn't have a web server. You need to use something like  `FROM php:7.2-apache`

Comment: Can you be more specific while referring "your application" and "does not work".

Comment: When I try to open the website I have: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, for php:7.2-apache still the same problem

Comment: Just search in the doc... `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-apache-php-app -v "$PWD":/var/www/html php:7.2-apache`

Comment: I would like to run this using Dockerfile.

Comment: I have ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED :(

Answer (score 49):

If you want to run some script "on the fly" with `php-cli` you can create the container and remove it immediately after the script execution.

Just go to the directory with your code and run:

**Unix**

```
docker container run --rm -v $(pwd):/app/ php:7.4-cli php /app/script.php
```

**Windows - cmd**

```
docker container run --rm -v %cd%:/app/ php:7.4-cli php /app/script.php
```

**Windows - power shell**

```
docker container run --rm -v ${PWD}:/app/ php:7.4-cli php /app/script.php
```

---

`--rm` will remove the container after execution

`-v $(pwd):/app/` will mount current directory

`php:7.4-cli` is the image

and `php /app/script.php` is the command which will be executed after the container is created

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Perfect for testing simple scripts and behaviour of old PHP versions. Thank you.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this, solved a problem I was having perfectly. Thanks, very useful!

Comment: Wonder, why this answer was not accepted - I tryed and all works. This answer should be accepted

Answer (score 24):

You can keep the same base image as you have `php:7.2-cli`:

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./index.php" ]
```

...build the image:

```
docker build -t my-php-app .
```

...run it:

```
docker run --rm --name hello-world-test my-php-app
```

You will obtain:

```
Hello World
```

Everything you did was correct except the port mapping (`-p 7000:80`) which is not necessary because you aren't running a web server.

== EDIT

If you want to run it as a web server, use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

...build it:

```
docker build -t my-php-app .
```

...and run it:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -d my-php-app
```

You will then have your PHP script running on 8080.

Comment: But I would like to run web server because I need to display my website in browser.

Comment: This post explains using Docker-copmpose https://thecodeframework.com/running-php-using-docker-compose-yml-file/

Answer (score 12):

1. Create simple php script:

```
echo '<?php echo "Working";' > my.php
```

2. Run docker:

```
docker  run -p 8080:8080 --rm -v $(pwd):$(pwd) php:7.4-cli php -S 0.0.0.0:8080  $(pwd)/my.php
```

3. Open in browser:

http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 3):

Many answers suggest using Apache for this, but that is not required. You need to have your application in the container run continuously on a specific port. You can keep the `php:7.2-cli` image, but your CMD should be different:

`CMD [ "php", "-S 0.0.0.0:80", "./index.php" ]`

This will run the built-in PHP webserver and after that you can expose it with the docker run command you already had

Comment: To avoid a "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed..." error, I had to modify the command to the following: `CMD [ "php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:80", "./index.php" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and simple example with **Docker** on **Windows 11**, assuming you have a similar directory structure as the example below:

```
C:\Users\YourName\Workspace\MyProject\program.php
```

And `program.php` has the following content:

```
<?php echo "It works!"; ?>
```

Then, in the Command Prompt, navigate to the project directory:

```
cd C:\Users\YourName\Workspace\MyProject
```

**Run with CLI**

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -v %CD%:/cli php:7.4-cli php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 /cli/program.php
```

View: http://localhost:8080

**Run with SERVER**

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8081:80 -v %CD%:/server --mount type=bind,source="%CD%",target=/var/www/html php:apache
```

View: http://localhost:8081/program.php

Then feel free to modify `program.php` and refresh the page.

**Environment**

- Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414
- Windows 11 Home, Version 22H2, OS build 22622.436